# Numpy matrix multiplication with custom dot product

Tags: numpy, vectorization, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

The default matrix multiplication is computed as

```
c[i,j] = sum(a[i,k] * b[k,j])
```

I am trying to use a custom formula instead of the dot product to get

```
c[i,j] = sum(a[i,k] == b[k,j])
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use broadcasting:

```
c = sum(a[...,np.newaxis]*b[np.newaxis,...],axis=1)  # == np.dot(a,b)

c = sum(a[...,np.newaxis]==b[np.newaxis,...],axis=1)
```

I included the `newaxis` in `b` just make it clear how that array is expanded.  There are other ways of adding dimensions to arrays (reshape, repeat, etc), but the effect is the same.  Expand `a` and `b` to the same shape to do element by element multiplying (or ==), and then sum on the correct axis.